# Flash video has become jittery in Karmic

Tags: ubuntu, video, ubuntu-9.10, flash, performance

When I first installed Karmic, I must have installed a Flash player or else it came with Karmic. It worked fine and I have been running the Ubuntu updates whenever requested by the OS. However, now my Flash video is extremely jittery and the whole computer kinds of slows down whenever I try to play a Flash video file. I have no idea what type of Flash player is running or what is the best one to use. Would appreciate any recommendations. Thanks.

**UPDATE:** **Graphics-heavy web pages also seem to cause these slow-downs and jittery graphics**. For example, scrolling a large page can sometimes cause the same graphic jitteriness as running a Flash video. Perhaps this is a graphics driver issue. Not sure how to check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VLC media player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player) can play Flash videos (that's what I use), there is no need to 
use Flash player for this. VLC media player runs on many platforms, including Linux.